# How to find a non-singular sub-matrix in a full-rank matrix.

Tags: matrices, matlab

Suppose we are given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, where $n<m$, and we know that $A$ is a full-rank matrix. What is a simple and efficient way to find any submatrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ constructed of columns of $A$, such that $B$ is not singular?
I want to have a Matlab function of the form `[ind]=find_B(A)` that returns indices of the columns of $A$ that allow constructing $B$.

Comment: Just find the columns iteratively/recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These $n$ columns will form a basis of the column space of $A$.  If you perform a row reduction the columns containing a leading $1$ will form such a basis.  If you use the Matlab command

```
[R,p] = rref(A)
```

the indices of those columns should be returned in p.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the function ```rref``` is not supported for code generation. Are there any other options? I do not want to implement this iterative search on my own! :)

Comment: @Arastas You may try the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). It is a build-in function in Matlab. Just do
$$
[Q,R,E]=qr(A);
$$
Then the first $n$ columns of $A*E$ are the basis you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You start with an empty set of column vectors. Then you iterate over columns in matrix $A$. If the column can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in the set, you skip the vector. Otherwise you add the vector to the set and continue. After you get n linearly independednt vectors, it is the matrix you are looking for.